# How to use OAuth in a background job that has no url

Tags: api, oauth, cron

We are using some public API that allows oauth authentication. And we have a scheduled job (cron job) that runs in the background, without a URL.

Setting up a server sat next to is what I think will work, but we would not like to do this. Can someone suggest a workaround to achieve the authentication in the background job? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the oauth2 client credentials grant is intended for. If you have an authorization server available which supports the client_credentials grant, then that is your best option.

The background job will be able to obtain a token from the authorization server via the client_credentials grant, using a client id and secret to authenticate, and receive a token in return. The obtained token can then be used to get access to the resource, in this case the API.

```
POST /token HTTP/1.1
Host: authorization-server.com
 
grant_type=client_credentials
&client_id=xxxxxxxxxx
&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxx
```

See e.g. https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/client-credentials/

Comment: If i need to enter my redirect uri to create an OAUTH client, what should I put?

Comment: Sorry, missed out the grant type, The provider's doc say to use SAML grant type, urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:saml2-bearer,

Comment: SAML is a different protocol. Doesn't the provider support OIDC or OAuth 2.0?

Comment: What I mean is: I'm not too familiar with SAML, the process might be a bit more complicated with SAML. Does the provider also support OpenId Connect or simply OAuth 2.0?

Comment: Seems not, they require to create a client with redirect URL. Anyways, thanks for the help

Comment: In that case I would ask the supplier of the product what is the right way to set things up in this case.

Answer (score -1):

If the OAuth grant requires authorization from an end user, then you'll need to share the access token that is obtained from the OAuth flow between the process that retrieves it (usually a web server) and the process that needs it (your background job).

If you plan to use the token for long periods of time, you'll likely need a refresh token so you can get a new access token without user intervention. Refresh tokens are made for this purpose (Google even calls the parameter you use to request one `offline_access`).

If you don't want to set up a server to handle the redirects, you can use a managed service like [Xkit](https://xkit.co). It manages the user interaction, and your background job can retrieve a valid access token with only an API key. *Disclosure: I work at Xkit*